# Connecting Postgresql to Django

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I am trying to connect 2 databases to django project so I can use one for develop and another on production

My setting file

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES["default"].update(db_from_env)

export DATABASE_URL=path_to_database
```

When i try to run server I got this error: "django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: PostgreSQL 12 or later is required (found 11.18)."

But when i write psql in terminal I got: psql (14.7 (Homebrew), server 15.2)
And PostgrSQL@11 is not installed on my mac

Comment: 1) You are connecting a Django app to a database not the other way around. 2) Your configuration code shows setting up for SQLite not Postgres. 3) What Django version?

Comment: I use ElephantSQL as service for remove database,
here i connect Django app to postgresql databse:
"db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES["default"].update(db_from_env)

export DATABASE_URL=path_to_database"
, I use django 4.2

Comment: You just repeated what was in the question, with no explanation of what the actual settings are. Also pretty sure `export DATABASE_URL=path_to_database` is not in your settings file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if `psql` client is connected to a newer version of `PostgreSQL` server, there might be additional `PostgreSQL` servers running on your machine.

You can find them by running `ps auxwww | grep postgres`.

Each running server listens on a distinct port number. Because `psql` client is connecting to `PostgreSQL@14.7`, this server is probably running on the port 5432 (that is the default port `psql` is connecting to).

Check your Django env config for the port number - probably Django is trying to connect to `PostgreSQL` server listening on a different port.